# HIVE : Read a struct value inside a map in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive table with a column of the below datatype:

```
map<int,struct<mot:bigint,id:bigint>>
```

I am trying to read the value for id from the map using lateral view explode and it throws the below error :

```
 select value.id from my_table lateral view explode(my_map) value  limit 10;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 1:14 Invalid column reference 'id'
```

**Can  anyone help me to read a struct value from a map.**

Answer (score 1):

```
select val.id from my_table lateral view explode(my_map) new_col as key,val limit 10;
```